# Where do you download NHibernate Castle Facility?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

I know it seems like a silly question, but its not clear from the castle project page/documentation.

I would need a version compatible with the latest version of NHibernate (2.1.2). Should I get the latest source from the github trunk and build it, or is there another place I should get it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HornGet:

http://hornget.net/packages/ioc/castle.facilities.nhibernateintegration/castle.facilities.nhibernateintegration-trunk

Castle TeamCity (login as a guest):

http://builds.castleproject.org/project.html?projectId=project28&tab=projectOverview

(The last successful build as of today:)
http://builds.castleproject.org/repository/download/bt54/5400:id/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration-.NETFramework-v3.5-13.zip

GitHub (Source):

http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration

The best place to ask these kinds of questions is probably the Castle Users Google Group:

http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users

Comment: Hornget appears to have become an advert site for meds.  I'd recommend the github link.

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, it seems like Hornget may be gone for good, which is sad.  I'm not sure if there is a nuget or OpenWrap alternative.